# How to convert a crypto::sha2::Sha256 hash into a &[u8] representation?

Tags: rust, sha256, sha

I'm currently trying to generate an ED25519 keypair from a SHA256 hash (via `rust-crypto` crate):

```
extern crate crypto; // rust-crypto = "0.2.36"

use crypto::ed25519;
use crypto::sha2::Sha256;
use crypto::digest::Digest;

fn main() {
    let phrase = "purchase hobby popular celery evil fantasy someone party position gossip host gather";
    let mut seed = Sha256::new();
    seed.input_str(&phrase);
    let (_priv, _publ) = ed25519::keypair(&seed); // expects slice
}
```

However, I totally fail to understand how to correctly pass the SHA256 to the `ed25519::keypair()` function. I traced down that `&seed.result_str()` results in:

```
"fc37862cb425ca4368e8e368c54bb6ea0a1f305a225978564d1bdabdc7d99bdb"
```

This is the correct hash, while `&seed.result_str().as_bytes()` results in:

```
[102, 99, 51, 55, 56, 54, 50, 99, 98, 52, 50, 53, 99, 97, 52, 51, 54, 56, 101, 56, 101, 51, 54, 56, 99, 53, 52, 98, 98, 54, 101, 97, 48, 97, 49, 102, 51, 48, 53, 97, 50, 50, 53, 57, 55, 56, 53, 54, 52, 100, 49, 98, 100, 97, 98, 100, 99, 55, 100, 57, 57, 98, 100, 98]
```

Which is something I do not want, something entirely different. The question now breaks down to:

```
   |
36 |     let (_priv, _publ) = ed25519::keypair(&seed);
   |                                           ^^^^^ expected slice, found struct `crypto::sha2::Sha256`
   |
   = note: expected type `&[u8]`
              found type `&crypto::sha2::Sha256`
```

How to correctly convert the `crypto::sha2::Sha256` hash into a `[u8]` representation?

Comment: It's hard to help without a complete example, that I can compile. I'm not certain which crypto library you are using, but I'll guess it's  [`rust-crypto`](https://crates.io/crates/rust-crypto) rather than [`crypto`](https://crates.io/crates/crypto), since the latter has no documentation and wasn't updated since 2014. Most users here won't be super familiar with these libraries so it would be useful if you include the actual dependencies, as well as `use` statements, so your code snippets can be compiled. 
See: [mcve]

Comment: Looking at your update.. The `[u8]` bytes that you've shown _really are_ the same as the `&str`. The error is because `keypair` expects a slice, not a `Sha256` struct.

Comment: Please can you reduce this post down to a single question. If it is just the updated part then please delete the rest and change the subject line.

Comment: Hi @PeterHall, thanks for your comments. It's indeed `rust-crypto`, I have totally rewritten the question, I hope it's more readable now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Sha256` API may be a little confusing at first because it is designed so that it doesn't allocate any new memory for the data. That's to avoid wasting a memory allocation, in case you want to allocate it yourself. Instead, you give it a buffer to write to:

```
// Create a buffer in which to write the bytes, making sure it's
// big enough for the size of the hash
let mut bytes = vec![0; seed.output_bytes()];
// Write the raw bytes from the hash into the buffer
seed.result(&mut bytes);

// A reference to a Vec can be coerced to a slice
let (_priv, _publ) = ed25519::keypair(&bytes);
```